# Show products in grid

Tags: products, product-list, grid-layout

I create my theme for magento and i can't show products in grid mode on my homepage.

I use this to show all products on my homepage but products is in list mode.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" name="product_random" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Here is my [catalog.xml](http://jsfiddle.net/Br7Lf/) and my [list.phtml](http://jsfiddle.net/G6wH7/)

Can you tell me what i need more to add for this grid mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>try `{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" name="product_random" mode="grid" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`</strike>

It should work.

Your problem is in `view.phtml` here:

```
<?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
```

so what you need is to set `$this->getMode()` to `grid`.

If you have a look into the `List.php`:

```
public function getMode()
{
    return $this->getChild('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
}
```

So you need to pass `grid` into `$toolbar->setData('_current_grid_mode', 'grid')` but I have no idea, how to do this.

So I see two possibilities here:

1. You copy the template and remove the list mode (bad idea)
2. You change the template the way, so that the grid mode is the default

Comment: I already use that.. but products is in list mode.. i wnat to be in grid..

Comment: Sorry, the `mode="grid"` get lost

Comment: Thank you, I try it but it don't work.. :/

Comment: updated. 7 more to go...

Comment: I tried all options and i don't know why i can't do that.. :/

This is my list.phtml http://jsfiddle.net/XN8LV/ . I try to delete list view.. and change position.. but nothing.. :/